# Why Is SharePoint Designer So Quirky

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I haven't been a SharePoint developer for too long, I just sort of got assigned a new project in the company I work for and it's all built against SharePoint. I've noticed SharePoint designer has a huge number of quirks. Here are the ones I can name off the top of my head:

- Randomly adding a large number of `nbsp;` into my code causing it not to run properly (This one took me a while to pin down)... Seriously, like 2 rows of just `nbsp;` in one of my html elements.
- Randomly adding code into my master page when I click on it to edit with no explanation and I didn't even know what it did.
- Not allowing me to connect to my SharePoint site for the longest time, and then one day it just started working and I'm not sure why.
- SharePoint designer error highlighting highlights things in my .aspx page saying something along the lines of it being invalid html, but then I go ahead and use it anyways and it works fine.
- A glitch where if I tried to edit code that was bordering between advanced-mode-only code and editable code while not in at advanced mode would cause the entire page to become uneditable (I've since realized I should just turn advanced mode on.

I'm sure there are plenty more quirks where those came from. How can such a widely used platform have so many inexplicable quirks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, these have been recurring issues with SharePoint Designer since the earliest versions (back when it was called FrontPage). The technology was initially acquired by Microsoft from Vermeer Technologies (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Vermeer_Technologies), and while it has been made better over time, it has never been anywhere near perfect.

Experienced users have simply learned what actions to avoid, like watching the ground as you walk to stop yourself from tripping.